# How can I improve upload / download speeds over socket server application?

Tags: java, sockets, stream, network-programming

I'm trying to upload a large file from my computer to another computer in a different network. However, the file transfer speed is incredibly slow. What is causing a bottleneck here in my code?

Code below is for the uploader:

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
    /*
     * Take a file, read it into a byte array using the File Input Stream
     * Then send that byte array using a Buffered Output Stream
     * Done
     */
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    
    File file = new File(fileToSend);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    byte[] byteArray = fis.readAllBytes();
    bos.write(byteArray);
    bos.flush();
    bos.close();
}
```

And here is what i'm using to download the file:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
    /*
     * Open up a socket, then get the byte array using a buffered input stream
     * then use a file output stream to write out the file
     */
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Socket socket = new Socket(hostName, port);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    byte[] byteArray = bis.readAllBytes();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileOutput);
    fos.write(byteArray);
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Download time: " + (end - start)/1000);
}
```

By slow, I mean that it takes about 6-7 minutes to upload a 100MB file over this program, as opposed to uploading on google drive which barely even takes a minute. I'm still trying to learn socket server programming so please do let me know where the bottleneck is.

Comment: The network path to google's servers is different than the network path to yours, and that may account for some or all of the speed differences. You can simplify and possibly speed up the transfers by using the `copy()` methods from the [`Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html) class.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading all bytes at once in your RAM by:

```
byte[] byteArray = fis.readAllBytes();
```

and after this your writing all bytes to your Socket:

```
bos.write(byteArray);
```

So you have to wait until all 100 MB are load from your file system and than you have to wait until these bytes are send. And at the downloader you do this the other way around.

You can reduce this time by splitting these two jobs in to seperate threads.

- The first thread is constandly reading n bytes (like 1024) from your FS and storing it in the shared synchronizedList.
- The second thread is reading the n bytes from the list and writing it to the client.

These Threads could also communicate with a PipedInputStream and a PipedOutputStream to each other:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PipedOutputStream.html

Furthermore you can used a compressed stream like GZIP:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html.

And you should think of using A(utomatic)R(esource)M(management)-Blogs
https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/trywithresources.html